# Suddenly graph API - returns 500 error for me/followedSites

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/followedSites` is returning 500 Internal Server Error

Here are the error details:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "generalException",
        "message": "General exception while processing",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-06-21T15:32:56",
            "request-id": "dc99093b-2426-4f66-a1b2-9a6f180c053c",
            "client-request-id": "b43fcb98-3a23-2f5d-90de-f4c009b5c8dd"
        }
    }
}
```

You can reproduce this on [Graph Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sites-list-followed?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-2)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I just checked again and I'm seeing the same behavior. If you click on the Graph Explorer link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sites-list-followed?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-2), log in with your Microsoft Account, and click on 'Run Query' you will see a 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: Are you logging into a tenant without a sharepoint license?

Comment: No, but the issue got resolved. see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/444844/graph-api-followed-sites-returning-http-error-code.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is an issue from the Microsoft side they have fixed it. More information is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/444844/graph-api-followed-sites-returning-http-error-code.html)